# Share processed state across components

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have three components. My `state` has a property named `state.selected`.

Currently in my `mapStateToProps` I am doing this in all three components:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
   return { selected:state.selected }
}
```

In each presentational component I then do the same processing called `getSelectedDisplays`. This function does some processing based on what is selected.

```
var PresentaionalComponent_1 = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
       var displays = getSelectedDisplays();
       // custom processing on `displays` for coponent 1
   }
})

var PresentaionalComponent_2 = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
       var displays = getSelectedDisplays();
       // custom processing on `displays` for coponent 2
   }
})

var PresentaionalComponent_3 = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
       var displays = getSelectedDisplays();
       // custom processing on `displays` for coponent 3
   }
})
```

### No control over parent component

I was hoping to avoid wrapping the three components in an extra div as my only need was to pass to them the result of `getSelectedDisplays`. I was hoping to avoid this:

```
 React.createElement(OverContainer)
```

and `OverContainer` would be the only one receiving `state.selected` and it would then do `getSelectedDisplays` then it will render the three components with it as a prop:

var OverPresentaional = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
         var { selected } = this.props;
         var display = getSelectedDisplays(selected);

```
     return React.createElement('div', {},
          React.createElement(PresentaionalComponent_1, { display });
          React.createElement(PresentaionalComponent_2, { display });
          React.createElement(PresentaionalComponent_3, { display });
     );
}
```

}});

Is this possible without wrapping them in a parent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [selector](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers), that will encapsulate getting the data from the state, and computing derived properties:

```
export const getSelectedDisplays = (state) => {
    const selected = state.selected;
    const selectedDisplays = // whatever logic you need to get selectedDisplays from selected
    return {
        selectedDisplays;
    };
};
```

Now for each component:

```
import { getSelectedDisplays } from 'selectorFile';

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
   return getSelectedDisplays(state);
}

var PresentaionalComponent_1 = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
       var displays = this.props.selectedDisplays;
       // custom processing on `displays` for coponent 1
   }
})
```

etc...

The only problem is, that getting the data, and the logic will be performed 3 times, instead of ones. To solve that, you can create a memoized selector, that will cache and return the same result, if the supplied params (state in this case) haven't changed. [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) is a library the creates memoized selectors for you.

Comment: Oh wow this looks very promising, thanks! I will test it out and let you know how it works out. Would you recommend going with this method, or wrapping it in a div-container and passing it down via a prop?

Comment: It depends on the case. If they do have a single parent, and the data is the same for the 3 of them, and the only overhead is a single `div`, I'll go with the div. If they don't have a single parent, or they need lots of different data objects from the store, I'll go with this method.